# How to catch exception while using preg_match?

Tags: php, exception

I have the following code, which works fine except when the pattern is not found and exception is thrown. How do I catch this error? Please help...

```
function GetUser($username) {
    $options  = array('http' => array('user_agent' => 'some_obscure_browser'));
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $site = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/' . $username, false, $context);

    $pattern = '/\"entity_id\":\"(\d+)\"/';
    
    if (!preg_match($pattern, $site, $matches)) {
        throw new Exception('User not found');
    }
    return $matches[1];
  }
```

Error Message

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.example.com/wrong_pattern): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\site\test.php on line 23
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: file_get_contents(https://www.example.com/wrong_pattern): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\site\test.php:36 Stack trace: #0 D:\XAMPP\htdocs\site\test.php(48): GetUser('wrong_pattern') #1 {main} thrown in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\site\test.php on line 36

Comment: `throw new Exception`, remove it or what?

Comment: I have to display error message if the pattern doesn't match so that user can try again.

Comment: I don't get that - what is the problem in catching that exception? The error message does not look related to anything in your code

Comment: @NicoHaase I ve tried explaining the issue in the comment below.

Answer (score 0):

put everything in try/catch block and if the error is thrown:

```
try {
    // your current code here
} catch( Exception $e ) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    // Or different way of handling that problem - depends on your needs
}
```

Comment: Above solution works partially. I am getting message repeated 3 times. Also warning error still there. Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.example.com/wrong_pattern): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\site\test.php on line 16
user not founduser not founduser not found

Comment: Looks like inserted URL is wrong and since that it can not locate user.

make echo $site; so you will be able to see what you are getting.

I am pretty sure URL is wrong though.

Comment: Let me explain. I have to check if example.com/abc is exist. If yes, the process moves fwd. If it does not exist, I want to throw error user, to check the URL again and enter correct URL i.e. example.com/abc. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: There is two part check. One with the URL and second with the username. If either one is wrong, error is to be displayed to the user.